# Is there any way we can use the batch processing feature in Mule Community edition?

Tags: java

Mule provides batch processing in the enterprise edition. Is there any way by which we can use it in the community edition ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Batch+Processing)

> Batch processing is exclusive to Mule Enterprise runtimes. To build applications with Batch jobs and run them in a test or production environment, you must build the application with an Enterprise runtime.

But I think you can test it out using a trial enterprise runtime, which is automatically bundled with Studio.